# BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I built a crud application using mern stack. Then I tried the search operation for the application but it show me this error:

> BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

This is my client side code:

Search.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Search = () => {

    const searchHandle = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const userName = e.target.search.value;
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/user/${userName}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

        console.log(typeof(userName));
    }

    return (
        <div className='px-3 py-2 w-3/4'>
            <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold mb-3'>Search User:</h1>
            <form onSubmit={searchHandle}>
                <input className='bg-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-3/4' type="search" name="search" id="name" />
                <button className='bg-blue-500 mx-2 py-2 px-4 rounded' type='submit'>Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

This is my server side code:

```
const expres = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');


const app = expres();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.use(cors());
app.use(expres.json())


const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:#@cluster0.moilkdv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

async function run() {
    try {
        const userCollection = client.db('simpleNode').collection('users');

        // get all users
        app.get('/user', async (req, res) => {
            const cursor = userCollection.find({});
            const users = await cursor.toArray();
            res.send(users);
        })


        // get a specific user for update
        app.get('/user/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const updateId = req.params.id;
            const updateQuery = { _id: ObjectId(updateId)}
            const user = await userCollection.findOne(updateQuery);
            res.send(user);
        })

        // updating user
        app.put('/user/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const userId = req.params.id;
            const user = req.body;
            const filter = { _id: ObjectId(userId) };
            const options = { upsert: true };
            const updatedUser = {
                $set: {
                    name: user.name,
                    address: user.address
                }
            }
            const result = await userCollection.updateOne(filter, updatedUser, options);
            res.send(result);
        })

        // creating users
        app.post('/user', async (req, res) => {
            console.log('post api called');
            const Nuser = req.body;
            const result = await userCollection.insertOne(Nuser);
            res.send(result);
        });

        // search query
        app.get('/user/:name', (req, res) => {
            const searchName = req.params.name;
            console.log(searchName);
        })

        // deleting user
        app.delete('/user/:id', async(req, res) => {
            const userId = req.params.id;
            const deleteQuery = { _id: ObjectId(userId)};
            const resut = await userCollection.deleteOne(deleteQuery);
            console.log("Delete complete of: ", userId);
            console.log(resut);
            res.send(resut);
        })
    }
    finally {
    }
}

run().catch(console.dir);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is running');
})


app.listen(port);
```

Please help to solve this error.

Comment: The error indicates that the value of `req.params.id` is not a valid [MongoDB ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) value. It looks like your client ask the server to search user by username while the server is search user by its id in the database

Comment: But I didn't even search. I was just trying to console log the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That request is sent to `app.get('/user/:id')` route.

`:id` or `:name` is just the name of the parameter.

We have to setup another route for searching, eg: change  `app.get('/user/:name')` to `app.get('/user/search/:name')`